# Nested FOR statement in IF ELSE

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop

Is it possible to Nest a FOR statement in to an IF ELSE statement?

i.e

I'm reading a variable for defining a software version. Which works if there is a version Specified. However if it's blank I was it to look for the Highest folder number instead.

So far I have:

```
IF %Softupgradeversion%=="" (
for /f "tokens=*" %%1 in ('dir /b /ad /on *') do (set latestdir=%%1
)) ELSE (
    SET latestdir=%Softupgradeversion%
    )
```

However if the variable is blank it doesn't work and go looking for the highest folder number. I would have though it's because the ()'s in the FOR statement as well as it being in IF ELSE ()'s. Is there like an escape character that could work like ^('dir /b /ad /on *'^) for example

Comment: Add the language tag.

Comment: Use `IF "%Softupgradeversion%"=="" (` .. that is, with double-quotes around the possible-empty value.  Also, in future, you should post what you actually get, not just "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *variable is blank* predicate is equivalent to *variable is not defined*, e.g. in terms of command line:

```
==>set Softupgradeversion
Environment variable Softupgradeversion not defined
```

To check that predicate in a batch script:

```
if "%Softupgradeversion%"=="" (
   echo Softupgradeversion is empty
) else (
   echo "%Softupgradeversion%"
)
```

or

```
if not defined Softupgradeversion (
   echo Softupgradeversion is empty
) else (
   echo "%Softupgradeversion%"
)
```

Note proper double quoting in `if "%Softupgradeversion%"==""`.

In fact, `if €%Softupgradeversion%€==€€` or even `if €%Softupgradeversion%==€` have nearly the same effect with almost any character in place of `€`. However, double quoting is the safest way as a variable could contain spaces or even some CLI-special characters that should be [escaped](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) as follows:

```
==>set "unusual=a space"

==>if "%unusual%"=="a space" echo good
good

==>if [%unusual%]==[a space] echo good
space]==[a was unexpected at this time.
```

or even

```
==>set "unusual=& > < |"

==>set unusual
unusual=& > < |

==>echo "%unusual%"
"& > < |"
```

Comment: Thanks it was the use of proper double quoting in if "%Softupgradeversion%"=="" that worked.

Also as mentioned above "Use IF "%Softupgradeversion%"=="" ( .. that is, with double-quotes around the possible-empty value"